# dc.js chart redrawing with new group function with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to redraw dc.js charts with new groups when other chart library click event.But it doesnt redraw.

Here is my javascript codes:

```
 var donemChart = dc.rowChart('div#donem'),
        hospitalTypeChart = dc.rowChart('div#hospital_type'),
        ckysHospitalClassChart = dc.rowChart('div#ckys_hospital_class'),
        ckysHospitalTypeChart = dc.rowChart('div#ckys_hospital_type'),
        hospitalHealthRegionChart = dc.rowChart('div#hospital_health_region'),
        hospitalRoleChart = dc.rowChart('div#hospital_role'),
        hospitalsChart = dc.rowChart('div#hospitals');




    d3.json('tsim.json',function(data){

        var ndx = crossfilter(data);
        var all = ndx.groupAll();




        //define crossfilter dimensions

        var donemDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.DONEM}),
                hospitalTypeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.KURUM_TURU}),
                ckysHospitalClassDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.CKYS_KURUM_TURU}),
                ckysHospitalTypeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.CKYS_KURUM_TIPI}),
                hospitalHealthRegionDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.SAGLIK_BOLGESI}),
                hospitalRoleDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.HASTANE_ROL}),
                hospitalsDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.HASTANE}) ;

        var donemGroup = donemDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
            hospitalTypeGroup = hospitalTypeDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
            ckysHospitalClassGroup = ckysHospitalClassDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
            ckysHospitalTypeGroup = ckysHospitalTypeDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
            hospitalRoleGroup = hospitalRoleDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
            hospitalsGroup = hospitalsDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
            hospitalHealthRegionGroup = hospitalHealthRegionDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say});







        donemChart
                .width(400)
                .height(300)
                .margins({top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
                .group(donemGroup)
                .dimension(donemDim)
                .ordinalColors(['#E89F00'])
                .label(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })

                .title(function (d) {
                    return "";
                })
                .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; })
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value; })
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().tickFormat();

        hospitalTypeChart
                .width(400)
                .height(300)
                .margins({top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
                .group(hospitalTypeGroup)
                .dimension(hospitalTypeDim)
                .ordinalColors(['#E89F00'])
                .label(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })

                .title(function (d) {
                    return d.value;
                })
                .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; })
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value; })
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().tickFormat();

        ckysHospitalClassChart
                .width(400)
                .height(300)
                .margins({top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
                .group(ckysHospitalClassGroup)
                .dimension(ckysHospitalClassDim)
                .ordinalColors(['#E89F00'])
                .label(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })

                .title(function (d) {
                    return "";
                })
                .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; })
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value; })
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().tickFormat();

        ckysHospitalTypeChart
                .width(400)
                .height(500)
                .margins({top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
                .group(ckysHospitalTypeGroup)
                .dimension(ckysHospitalTypeDim)
                .ordinalColors(['#E89F00'])
                .label(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })

                .title(function (d) {
                    return "";
                })
                .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; })
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value; })
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().tickFormat();


        hospitalHealthRegionChart
                .width(400)
                .height(500)
                .margins({top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
                .group(hospitalHealthRegionGroup)
                .dimension(hospitalHealthRegionGroup)
                .ordinalColors(['#E89F00'])
                .label(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })

                .title(function (d) {
                    return "";
                })
                .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; })
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value; })
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().tickFormat();

        hospitalRoleChart
                .width(400)
                .height(500)
                .margins({top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
                .group(hospitalRoleGroup)
                .dimension(hospitalRoleDim)
                .ordinalColors(['#E89F00'])
                .label(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })

                .title(function (d) {
                    return "";
                })
                .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; })
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value; })
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().tickFormat();


        hospitalsChart
                .width(1000)
                .height(25000)
                .margins({top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0})
                .group(hospitalsGroup)
                .dimension(hospitalsDim)
                .ordinalColors(['#E89F00'])
                .label(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                })

                .title(function (d) {
                    return "";
                })
                .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value; })
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value; })
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().tickFormat();

        chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function(event){

            if(event.item.dataContext.d_type==1){

                var donemGroup = donemDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
                        hospitalTypeGroup = hospitalTypeDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
                        ckysHospitalClassGroup = ckysHospitalClassDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
                        ckysHospitalTypeGroup = ckysHospitalTypeDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
                        hospitalRoleGroup = hospitalRoleDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
                        hospitalsGroup = hospitalsDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say}),
                        hospitalHealthRegionGroup = hospitalHealthRegionDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_muayene_say});

                dc.redrawAll();



            }else if(event.item.dataContext.d_type==2){

                var donemGroup = donemDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_A_grubu_ameliyat_say}),
                        hospitalTypeGroup = hospitalTypeDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_A_grubu_ameliyat_say}),
                        ckysHospitalClassGroup = ckysHospitalClassDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_A_grubu_ameliyat_say}),
                        ckysHospitalTypeGroup = ckysHospitalTypeDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_A_grubu_ameliyat_say}),
                        hospitalRoleGroup = hospitalRoleDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_A_grubu_ameliyat_say}),
                        hospitalsGroup = hospitalsDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_A_grubu_ameliyat_say}),
                        hospitalHealthRegionGroup = hospitalHealthRegionDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.toplam_A_grubu_ameliyat_say});


                dc.redrawAll();
            }





            dc.redrawAll();


        });








        dc.renderAll();






    });
```

When click the chart I am getting data type after I am cheking the data type in chart listener function.And I am grouping the dimension with new group.When it is consol logged new groups show but it doesnt effect with redrawing the charts.

What can I do this problem? How can we solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just reassigned the reference of the `hospitalTypeGroup` variable (for example) to a different object. But the chart is still holding the reference to the old object. You have to reset the group on the `hospitalTypeChart` with `hospitalTypeChart.group(hospitalTypeGroup)`, then re-render. (I don't think redrawing will work here in a lot of cases.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to alert dc.js of the changed groups.

Just creating new dimensions and groups with the same names does not replace them. You will need to also call `.group()` for each chart appropriately.

Also, I wouldn't recommend creating new groups (or dimensions) every time something is clicked. Crossfilter will slow down with each new group, since all of them need to respond to each filter action. Instead, create the groups ahead of time and just apply them in the click handler.

Comment: Gordon Thanks , But how we can use crossfilter filter function?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Can you illustrate or link an example about the question ?